# Poll vs Push... which would be better for multiple emails in an app?

Tags: android, push-notification, polling, email

I am working on an Android APP that will handle multiple email accounts, POP3 and IMAP.  The current APP, to check for email, you open the APP and click on an update feature.   That logs into each email account, and checks for any new mail.  Although this works, we need a more efficient, and timely check for new messages.

At first I thought PUSH was the way to go but from what I have read on here, that may not be ideal... especially with multiple IMAP accounts.   If I understand right, it keeps each IMAP connection open long-term which could cause some other issues and not sure I could even use it with POP3 accounts.

I looked into POLL as an alternative but that too has potential issues.   That involves how frequent it fires up and does the account "checks", the amount of time that takes, and how that all effects battery life.  In addition, there appears to be several different "ways" to schedule the POLL option (AlarmManager, JobScheduler, and SyncAdapter)... and I assume one might be better than the other... especially with new version of Android that let you "quiet" your device at certain times of the day.

So the question is, based on what we are looking to do, which is the better way to handle this capability?   I am leaning towards PUSH (which format...still unsure), but don't want to waste hours of time to find out that I went down the wrong path.

Thanks ahead for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

IMAP supports [IDLE Command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMAP_IDLE) in which client acts as passive entity depending/relying upon the server to notify arrival of new mails in account. But as you correctly figured out that it will keep connection open and other issues of rebuilding the connection if it gets disturbed due to any possible reason.

POP do not provide such passive capability to clients. Clients have to pull the mails from server.

From my experience, total synchronization of account on client side is not a problem but it requires too many things to be taken care of like parsing the mail content, maintaining the active list of mails in an account's folder, etc.

[1] Very simple synchronization mechanism would be to simply show the `MailList` and whenever a message is clicked upon then dynamically load the content of mail.

`MailList` = Sorted order of Mail Entries in an account's folder.

`Single Mail Entry` = `Sender` + `Mail Subject` + `Mail Date & Time` + `Mail Size`

This method of showing MailList initially and fetching the mail content on demand can be achieved via both:

- IMAP (FETCH Subject, INTERNALDATE, Sender, Size) and
- POP (TOP n m {TOP is a POP command which can fetch `m` number of lines of `nth` mail's body along with complete MailHeaderSection of `nth` mail}). Afterwards MailHeaderSection can be parsed and MailList can be constructed.

[2] Simply fetch the **complete** mail and store accordingly. Now, Parse it on demand and show it to user. This is also readily supported in both:

- IMAP (FETCH BODY.PEEK[])
- POP (RETR n)

I like this method since its simple.

Both the above methods are working as if client is active entity (pulling mails on demand).

Comment: We basically due that but the app needs to log into each account to get the "new" vs "old" mail... and then let the user know that there is NEW mail to see.    But we need a mechanism to actually check for NEW mail automatically... either PUSH or POLL.   Sounds like PUSH may definately not be ideal then cause of IMAP and POP3 issues.

Comment: @Peter: If you are **only** concerned with showing if an account's folder has new mail without actually fetching them completely then this requirement is easily satisfied by both IMAP and POP. You just need to maintain the list of mail already downloaded. Both in IMAP and POP there are unique identifiers assigned to mails. You need to just work with these unique identifiers if you just need to show that there are new mails in an account's folder.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding... We have that.  Again, the APP does all this... PROVIDED... we open the APP and let it check.   That is not the problem, or the question.   We need to AUTOMATE this check process when the APP is NOT running... hence, PUSH or PULL question.

Comment: Well, then PULL will be the better option. Also it depends upon how app is written and whether its allowed to run in background. Because in PUSH, if user stops the background activity and hence new mail notification won't be received in APP. Same is applicable to PULL. But in PUSH, if the APP or platform allows background activity then you need to maintain and ensure the connection is active all the time.